# Variety over a finite field as a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

In Hartshorne's book, a functor $t$ is defined (II.2.6) from the category of varieties over an algebraically closed field $\kappa$ (Ch I) to the category of schemes over $\operatorname{Spec}\kappa$. I was wondering if it is possible to define in a similar fashion a functor $t'$ from the category of varieties over arbitrary fields $k$ (that is, locally ringed spaces that are locally isomorphic to set of zeros of some polynomials over $k$) to the category of functors over $\operatorname{Spec}k$ such that for every affine variety $V$ with ring of regular functions $A(V)$

$$ t'(V) = \operatorname{Spec}A(V). $$

In particular I am interested in the case when $V$ is a variety defined over some finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: What does a variety over an arbitrary field mean to you? In the sense that with your definition the locally ringed space $(\varnothing,\mathcal{O})$ where $\mathcal{O}(\varnothing)$ is the zero ring is a variety over $\mathbb{R}$ both for $\Spec(0)$ (where $0$) is the zero ring and $\Spec(\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2+1))$. The whole point of needing algebraically closed is that non-algebraically closed fields can't differentiate polynomials by their values on that field.

Comment: @AlexYoucis A variety here is, for example, the set of points in $\mathbb{F}_q^2$ that satisfy some polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_q[x_1,x_2]$ or $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{F}_q)$, with its shaves of regular functions.

Comment: @JavierLinares Alex's objections apply here too. For example, take any irreducible polynomial in one variable with no root in $\mathbb{F}_q$. This defines a non-empty scheme (of finite presentation, integral, etc.), but it has no $\mathbb{F}_q$-rational points. To put it another way, there is no Nullstellensatz for fields that are not algebraically closed, so not every radical ideal is the vanishing ideal of some set of rational points.

Comment: @ZhenLin Oh, I just forgot that we can't assign an ideal to each affine variety an ideal... let me edit the question.

Comment: @JavierLinares It just can't be done. You can't have a good theory by just thinking of the $\mathbb{F}_q$-points.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Okey I see... let me change my question then. Let's image you have a bunch of polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_q[x_0,\dots,x_m]$ defining a quasi-projective variety $V$ over $\mathbb{F}$, the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_q$. How can I define a scheme $X$ of finite type over $\mathbb{F}_q$ such that the $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$-rational points of $X$ are identified with points of $V$ with coordinates in $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$? Thanks a lot for your helpful comments, by the way.

Comment: @JavierLinares You should just learn schemes :) Once you do that, the obvious answer is just $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_q[x_1,\ldots,x_m]/(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$ where $f_i$ are your polynomials. There are lots of ways that you can try and cheat the system ``geometrically integral quasi-projective schemes are equivalent to irreducible quasi-projective varieties (in the classical sense) with a continuous action of the absolute Galois group'' but they're all just more painful than just learning schemes.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Absolutely right, I feel like learning schemes is an investment I should have made a long time ago. Anyway, the projective line over $\mathbb{F}$ has $q$+1 points with coordinates in $\mathbb{F}_q$ but $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_q[x_0,x_m])$ has $q^2$ $\mathbb{F}_q$-rational points. I think that taking Spec works in the affine case but I don't know how to proceed in general.

Comment: @JavierLinares I mean, again the answer is caught up in the theory of schemes. I mean, if $X$ is projective variety, then there exists finitely many homogenous polynonmials $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ in $k[x_0,\ldots,x_m]$ such $X=\mathrm{Proj}(k[x_0,\ldots,x_m]/(f_1,\ldots,f_m))$. If you want quasi-projective as an open subset of some $X$  then you need to take finitely many homogenous elements $a_1,\ldots,a_\ell$ in $k[x_0,\ldots,x_m]/(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$ and consider the open subscheme $D(a_1,\ldots,a_\ell)$ in $\mathrm{Proj}(k[x_0,\ldots,x_m]/(f_1,\ldots,f_n))$. I don't know how helpful this is if you

Comment: don't know scheme theory. So, again, I'd just go suggest reading Gortz and Wedhorn (I think the most user friendly introduction--good balance between rigor and readability).

Comment: @AlexYoucis I'll have a look at it, thanks again!

Comment: In the case $k=\mathbb{R}$, we have an endomorphism of the real classical affine line
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{R}&\to \mathbb{R}\\
a&\mapsto \frac{1}{a^2+1}.
\end{align*}
$$
This should somehow induce a map $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{R}[x]\to\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{R}[x]$ of schemes over $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{R}$. Equivalently, an endomorphism of real algebras $\mathbb{R}[x]\to\mathbb{R}[x]$. But it seems to be no natural choice for this map.

Comment: Also, a classical (affine) variety $X$ over a finite field $k$ is a locally ringed space over $k$ which has an underlying topological space that is discrete and whose structure sheaf (of regular functions) is the sheaf of *all* $k$-valued functions. In other words, the étale space of $\mathcal{O}_X$ is the discrete topological space on the set $\coprod_{x\in X}k$. Hence, a morphism between classical varieties $X$ and $Y$ over $k$ is *any function* $X\to Y$. For these reasons, it is foreseeable that classical varieties over finite fields will not be very interesting.